# How to calculate Skeletal Muscle Ratio(%)(SMR%) statistically by using formula(without using weighing machine or any online calculators)?

Tags: weight, muscle, musculoskeletal-system, height, body-mass-index-bmi

How are we supposed to calculate individual's Skeletal Muscle Ratio in percentage(SMR %) if we have results of an individual that includes: `age` `gender` `weight` `height` `BMI` and `BMR`?

I have researched a lot but I am not able to find the formula for calculating SMR percentage according to the variables I gave above. Can someone provide me with a source for the formula?

Comment: I don't think you can calculate skeletal muscle ratio from the variables you've mentioned. BMI can increase due to fat or muscle gain. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jan I just need to know the formula for my project by which I can calculate the SMR%. If not these variables what is the formula to calculate SMR% without using the above Variables.

Comment: First, you need to know the percent of body fat. This can be estimated from the thickness of the skin folds, etc. Anyway, I think you'll more likely find an answer on https://fitness.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Jan I tried searching on [https://fitness.stackexchange.com](https://fitness.stackexchange.com) but I was unable to find any appropriate results for the same. Well Lets Suppose I find out Body Fat (Kg) after that How am I suppose to find the result for SMR in %.

Comment: No, I mean you can ask this question there and they will likely know.